# View a list of URLs that I Like in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm testing the Like button out, and I'd like to check which 'Likes' have been recorded against a Facebook account.

How do I view a full list of URLs that I've previously Liked?

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of URLs that you have "liked" by using the [Developer APIs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

You will need to use the [fql.multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery) method in the Facebook Query Language.

Enter this query exactly as is in to the queries text box in the test console:

```
{"query1":"SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me()","query2":"SELECT title, summary, url FROM link WHERE link_id in (SELECT object_id FROM #query1)"}
```

The multiquery method is very particular about whitespace.

This will return a list of all objects that you have liked
[image]

and then underneath this it will then return a list of Links that you have liked.
[image]

You must be logged in to Facebook in order for this to work.

Comment: It says "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column." :-(

Comment: The list you get back from the "like" table is only partial. If you look carefully at the actual feed on your page, you'll see any "like" you made outside of facebook is NOT returned. ARGH.

Answer (score 0):

When you "like" an external URL (e.g. via a facebook plugin), it seems to store it somewhere else (the `url_like` table rather than the `like` table). I was able to get the results for this using the FQL below:

```
SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me()
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Activity Log and select Likes

[image: Likes Filter]