# Finding websites that have been 'Liked' on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-like

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to find third party websites that have been 'liked' on Facebook.

I can't seem to find a search function on Facebook for this, so I tried searching using Google but none of the searches returned what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can check via the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) using the `ids` query.

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://apple.com

```
{
   "http://apple.com": {
      "id": "http://apple.com",
      "shares": 141119
   }
}
```

Depending on the website and whether a Like button was available on that page you may get the number of shares instead.

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/

```
{
   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/": {
      "id": "110935752279118",
      "name": "Inception (2010)",
      "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/71156_110935752279118_1973266_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/",
      "category": "Movie",
      "website": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/",
      "description": "Directed by Christopher Nolan. With Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page, Ken Watanabe.",
      "likes": 46015
   }
}
```

Comment: I was actually hoping to find sites, rather than check ones Ive already found

Comment: @jackster For yourself ? If so then http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10969/facebook-how-can-i-view-a-list-of-urls-that-i-like